# A 50s/60s Horror B-Movie with a wobbly-spiked monster

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I'm trying to identify a movie which I recall being terrified by when I was maybe 4 or 5 years old.  I can only remember one scene, but hopefully I can provide enough information for someone to identify it...

- Probably from the 50s/60s
- Definitely the sort of thing you'd call a b-movie.
- I *think* it was colour, but the scene in question had a monster which I remember as being grey (or at least not very colourful).
- The scene I remember was of a monster a bit bigger than a human (it was clearly a person in an all-encompassing rubbery suit) lurching towards the camera having just come through a door.  The door was backlit.
- The monster had long spikes which wobbled as it walked.
- Probably not very helpful, but it was shown on TV at the same time (but on a different channel) as The Towering Inferno in the UK some time around 1985-6.  My best guess is that it was at the same time as [this showing](http://genome.ch.bbc.co.uk/02ccc70db98b4d72bd8041a5e554054e), but sadly I can't find any online archives of ITV listings from that day (which is the the most likely channel)

I've attached a picture of how I remember it
[image]

I know it's a bit of a long shot but this has been bugging me for *years*

Comment: Would you settle for [bumps](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mviLfx3o70Q/hqdefault.jpg)? ;)

Comment: Was it definitely a movie? The description has an air of a Star Trek or Space 1999 episode.

Comment: @mungflesh - No, it could well have been a TV show.  It was always a movie in my mind (because my Mum kept switching between that and The Towering Inferno each time that I decided I was brave enough to watch it) but come to think of it, there's no reason it would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might be an episode from "Voyage to the Bottom of the Sea"(1964-1968 TV series). It sounds like the 8th episode from season 3, 'The Thing from Innerspace'. It's from the 1960's and it is in color and the creature does come shambling through a doorway.

Here is the entire episode from Youtube. You can see the spiky monster coming through a doorway at at least two points, 40.10 and 48.18.

Comment: Neither of those shambling through the doorway bits look as dramatic as it is in my memory, but the way those spikes wobble is unmistakeable! That's it! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Guy. I'm glad I found it, it was really bothering me too!

Answer (score 2):

The 'look' isn't quite what you describe but I'm making allowances for your age at the time you watched it.

[**The Thing From Another World**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0044121/) (1951) has the **backlit** creature in a doorway.

[image]

Some good bits collected in a YouTube video.

Note that the movie was originally in Black and White but a colorised version was made available a few years later.

[image]

This movie was remade as [**The Thing**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084787/) by John Carpenter in 1982

Comment: Looking at the clip, that's pretty much exactly how I remember the backlit door scene, but the monster is the one in the guest's answer. It could well be I'm mixing memories.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but could it be the ["Creature from Black Lagoon"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046876/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)? Maybe this is the scene that you remember:

[image]

Comment: That's a publicity photo, not sure it's actually a scene in the movie.

Comment: Possible! But it shows well how the monster in the movie is. So it might help to identify it.